# While enabling the example storage engine error: "./configure: No such file or directory "

Tags: mysql

I am trying to enable the **example storage** engine in **mySQL** by the following command

```
./configure –with-example-storage-engine
```

But while executing the above command, the following error is thrown:

> ./configure: No such file or directory

Can anyone please help me to eradicate it?

Comment: Is there actually a file called `configure` in the current directory when you run the command? Did you `cd` into the source folder first?

Comment: Ya the `configure` file is at the path `/home/Desktop/mysql-5.5.34/configure.cmake` but i executed the command from **mysql-5.5.34** directory

Comment: also check the permission level of the file directories

Comment: Current versions of mysql use `cmake` as their building system. Thats why `configure` does not exist.

Comment: @Sagar i am using root user,so there is no problem regarding permission level

Comment: @niese is there any other way to enable the example storage without using `configure` ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to build mysql with the example storage engine?

Comment: Hmm ok, I wish you good luck. But determine how to build mysql using cmake, is a peace of cake compared to writing an own engine.

Answer (score 3):

You should read the documentation for building the source of the version of MySQL you are using. As @t.niese commented, the `./configure` method is not used any more (since MySQL 5.5 IIRC).

There are options for cmake to enable/disable features at build time, including storage engines.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/source-configuration-options.html#option_cmake_storage_engine_options